# Impact of a row-major ordered program in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have a big software written in Fortran 77 running on Linux that uses multidimensional arrays for storing time-indexed matrices and with several, different series, but the indexing order is that of a row-major ordering like C. However, Fortran is column-ordered and there are cache-miss penalties when the values are indexed sequentially.

As a example, I have two series of 100.000 10x10 matrices. I'm storing them as:

```
MATRIX(2, 100000, 10, 10)
```

but as I understand, if the values are intended to be accessed linearly, the optimum declaration for Fortran would be

```
MATRIX(10, 10, 100000, 2)
```

Right now the impact of refactoring all the code to use the other ordering system would be big, but I would like to have an idea of the potential impact.

**Is there any way I could easily measure the impact of having the wrong ordering system, to estimate the potential improvement of changing it?**

Maybe some automatic measure of cache misses or cache misses associated to those arrays.

Comment: It can be several times slower, but you should try and measure.

Comment: No, the only way you can determine the improvement is to actually test it both ways.

Comment: Make sure to test with and without compiler optimization options. For simple cases, the compiler is able to reorder loops to take data alignment into account.

Comment: A key thing to look at in timing test is passing sub-arrays to subroutines.  In your first case the compiler needs to make a copy in order to pass contiguous data to the subroutine, in the second it's already set to just pass a pointer. (Of course in f77 you have to order that way in order to *simply* pass sub-arrays.)

Comment: Is the array used as a sparse array or does it access sequential elements frequently?  You probably won't see any difference if it is accessed as a sparse array.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It is not easy just to try without an idea of the improvement: the code is big and a lot of parts should be modified (array is accessed directly, there is no Getter or Setter). @cup, the array usually is accessed sequentially but there are exceptions. In addition, some processing is done locally, not on the arrays directly, so I'm unsure of the potential benefits.

Comment: If it ain't broke don't fit it.  If you want to explore the question write some small demo programs that mimic the typical operations in the real program for timing tests.